# Castle Windsor Releasing Components

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

EDIT:

I've completed rephrased the question as I've been able to simplify my problem down to the following:

```
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().LifeStyle.Singleton);
        var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
        container.Kernel.ReleaseComponent(foo);
        var foo2 = container.Resolve<IFoo>();

        Assert.IsTrue(foo != foo2) // this fails

public interface IFoo : IDisposable { }

public class Foo : IFoo {
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

I must be doing something really stupid here...any idea what?

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish here is for a all resolutions of a component to return the same instance for some period of time (a scope). If there is a better way of accomplishing this, I'm certainly open to it.

EDIT:
Ok, so I RTFM and apparently this is by design. Is the best way of accomplishing what I want here still a custom lifestyle manager?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, if that's the behavior you want, then custom lifestyle it must be

Comment: Thanks. I added a custom class inheriting from AbstractLifestyleManager to do this, but Release is never called when I call ReleaseComponent. It looks like Release only gets called if the ReleasePolicy.HasTrack on the Kernel returns true, but that isn't happening for all components...Could you advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Foo` is `PerThread`. That means you will get a new instance... if you request it on another thread. If I understand you correctly, the issue is with the lifestyle you've chosen, not how you release components.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't explaining clearly. I still have the same problem if it is a Singleton. I think the issue is that the injected Func<IFoo> in MyType holds a list of "Resolved Instances" internally and doesn't call container.Resolve internally each time I invoke the Func. Accordingly, I may 1. Invoke the Func and get an instance back. 2. Have someone else on the thread, or anywhere if Singleton, use then call .Dispose on that instance. 3. The instance gets removed from the container, but subsequent calls to the same Func<IFoo> return the disposed instance instead of a new one...